# iLo4 and AlmaLinux\Centos8 do not work properly

Tags: hp-proliant, ilo

I have a HP DL360p G8 and I have updated all firwamres such as Bios, iLo and .. to the latest version but problem is when I open Virtual Console i can work with first connection and when I close that session and reopen it later I see this error:
[image: pic]

and I can not work with virtual console in second time or future and I should reboot the server,
any idea what is the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try just typing into the console?

Comment: yes i entered any key on my keyboard and even awaken the cursor!

Comment: Then what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hit Enter in the console window to awaken the cursor.
This should be very easy to test.

Comment: i did it but no sucess

Answer (score 1):

Interrupt remapping does this on the G8 HP Servers (also on Debian, multiple reports on Proxmox forums) after kernel 5.4, making virtual console unusable. You can see this by booting a CentOS 7 LiveCD, which should work without any problems for long periods of time.

Try to disable remapping by pressing 'e' on grub to edit your kernel and adding 'intremap=off' or 'nointremap' at the end of your boot options. If that fixes your problem, add it permanently by using grubby, if not, try also setting intel_iommu off and booting with both options disabled, people have had success with that.

Answer (score 0):

To complete [schris's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1081947/91317), RHEL (and derivatives RockyLinux, AlmaLinux) 8.4+ (with kernel 4.18.0-240+, according to https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=18223, integrating some 5.x iommu patches) are also affected.

Instead of completely disabling interrupt remapping at all, for me disabling interrupt remapping source-id checking with `intremap=nosid` was enough (documentation: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html).

To make this change permanent, add this argument to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub` and regenerate the grub config `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

Also, some of the exchanges mentioned and resources I found:

- https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/keyboard-and-mouse-input-not-working-with-pve-7-0-installer-and-hp-ilo4.92035/
- https://bugzilla.proxmox.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3507
- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214795
- https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/updated-to-ve-7-0-no-web-gui-dmar-errors-on-console.92022/

Thoses links also mentions the following solutions (none working for me on RockyLinux 8.5 installer):

- disabling hpwdt module (`modprobe.blacklist=hpwdt rd.driver.blacklist=hpwdt`)
- disabling iommu completely (`intel_iommu=off`)
- settings `intremap=no_x2apic_optout`